# Crystal Report needs password and Login Id and this is not known to me .?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Hello everyone I am using Crystal Reports on VS 2010.
I have created a report using ADO Dotnet datasets which is connected with my sqlite Database S3 file.
I haven't provide any username and password in this process. But when I run my form using Crystal Report Viewer. It asks for Username and Password.

Any help regarding the default Username and Password or any step that I am missing will be a help.

Comment: are you using wizard ? http://www.mindcracker.com/Story/482/create-a-crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: yes I am using Wizard

Comment: I have gone through all these steps but in the end its asking for LoginID and Password which i never Provided

Comment: are you using VS 2010  - profession ?

Comment: give snippet of your code

Comment: I havent written a single line all by GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to me you are creating crystal report with database connectivity, so just put the username and password of database, then you can access it.

for more better answer, please post your code here, so that i can resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SQL Server Database";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "my_testConnection";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "123";
```

}